# How would I apply an image texture to a 'procedural object'?

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes

I have created a node tree that uses a number of simple shapes (based around a cube or point) to create a more complex single shape (futuristic vehicle as seen below). I would now like to apply a texture (or livery) of 'go-faster stripes to the resultant shape. The aim is to 'wrap' the image over the procedural object as illustrated. The image below shows 3 iterations of the procedural object viewed from above, the overall size will change so I would want to apply some procedural mapping to keep the image on context with the object. After watching numerous Youtube videos I am none the wiser and all I seem to be able to achieve is applying an image texture to each of the component parts. The problem seems to be convincing the Shader Editor to treat the 'procedural object' as normal object, If I could find out how to do that the rest is plain sailing. Can anybody point me in the right direction (and thanks to Robin Betts for his posting help) Cheers!
[image: visualization of objectives]

I have created a paired down file to illustrate (and hopefully troubleshoot my issue).
Here is a screen capture of the very basic shade editor and the result of applying it to a procedural object generated from three primary shapes. The texture coordinate and mapping do nothing as far as I can see.
[image: base procedural shader]

As I have previously said what I am after is the ability to drop a texture on a procedural object that wraps like a UV.
I'd happily upload the blend file and the texture file if I could find out how to do it.
Apologise for being so clumsy as I'm not familiar with the sites protocols yet.

Comment: The text at the bottom of the three overheads should read "image textures"....more haste, less speed.

Comment: If you didn't "bake" the text into the image, it would be easier to edit ;) A shader shouldn't have a problem using an image texture on a geonodes generated mesh: typically you won't have a UV Map on such geometry (it's not hard to get a UV map of SOME, probably bad quality). It seems in this case you want to use a texture coordinate: $xy$ for your image texture - which is the default thing done when you pass "Texture Coordinate: generated" to the "Image Texture" node. Show us the shader you have tried so we can advise further.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thanks for your advice. I have updated with a screen shot of the very basic shade editor. As I said in my original post; can the Shade Editor be convinced to treat a procedural object as a primary shape when applying an image texture? My suspicion is that is can but not for a newbie such as myself.

Comment: Try "Generated" texture coordinate, and default Image Texture settings: https://i.imgur.com/es5afrv.png

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thank You Markus, that was what I was after.

Comment: To share your Blender file, you can use https://blend-exchange.com/. It will provide a link after uploading. Just copy-past this link by editing your question (not in the comments). For the texture, you can include it as an image in your question also (as you did for screen captures).

Comment: Thank you @StefLAncien, I appreciate the information,,,,,very helpful.